# Can not retrieve location share on smartphone browser

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I try to take my location by using the share location html5 geolocation on the browser, when run in PC browser it appears a notif to allow access share location, while when I try on my smartphone browser chrome / firefox it does not work ... so my question..

1. whether when share location it only take Lat / Lot according from my IP ..
2. When share location why is not accurate, is taking the location of my card provider phone.
3. whether to use the GPS feature on our smartphone to take the location through the browser.

Comment: Your intention is pretty unclear and your questions seem to point in different directions, but on a smartphone this notification might be disabled due to existing system settings affecting the browser or the location service as a whole.

Comment: thanks @cepharum, My questions are all related to the share location or get the location of the browser, so sorry if hard to understand. So the possibility can not get a share location on the browser on the smartphone.

Comment: What about your system settings on smartphone? Are positioning services enabled or not? Is browser permitted to basically access/provide location data? E.g. when running your browser for the first time after setting up your phone it might ask once to gain access on location data and you decline it. After that the related notification won't ever pop up again unless you reset the related system setting.

Comment: Yes all I have settings on my smartphone, and indeed at that time only once ever appear notif and then no more, whether the location obtained from the share location of an IP address?

Comment: This may depend on the particular smartphone, its operating system and version as well as the browser used.